# Postgresql create TRIGGER for a two column ts_vector using tsearch2

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search, tsvector

Hi I am trying to learn how to use Full text search in postgres using version 9.2.2.

```
Here is my database:
title : character varying(1024)
body  : text
body_title_tsv | tsvector
```

I then defined the body_title_tsv to be a ts_vector made up from body and title fields, with coalesce to handle nulls.

```
UPDATE pg_rocks_post SET body_title_tsv = to_tsvector( coalesce(body,'') || coalesce (title,''));
```

I want to know how to write a TRIGGER that handles updates on "title" and/or "body".

I know I can create a Trigger using syntax like this and the tsearch2 function.

```
    CREATE TRIGGER body_title_tsv_trig BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT on pg_rocks_post 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE tsearch2(body_title_tsv , title);
```

I can do the same with body instead of title.

My Question is how do I combine the two to update the body_title_tsv

Or do I have to learn how to write my own function that essentially runs the
SQL for body_title_tsv when UPDATE occurs? .

I know the other way to address this issue is to create an INDEX. But I am trying to understand how to write a trigger and read examples that use tsearch2 in the PostgreSQL book by Kory and Susan Douglas.

Edit: I came across this function that does this . Its the "tsvector_update_trigger" function. I am still interested in knowing if there is a way to do this using tsearch2.

```
create trigger body_title_tsv_trig BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT on pg_rocks_post FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE tsvector_update_trigger(body_title_tsv,'pg_catalog.english',title,body);
```

Comment: The last function is the one you're looking for. Tsearch2 is obsolete and was replaced by the built-in text search functions.

Answer (score 1):

I would go about this somewhat differently.  It seems like you want a consistent search interface for your table, and the best way to do this is to design it in a function.  You can then index the output of the function.  Note the function *does not* hit the table, and only operates on tuple data, and this is why we can index its output safely.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tsv(pg_rocks_post) RETURNS tsvector LANGUAGE SQL AS
 $$
 SELECT tsvector(coalesce($1.title, '') || ' ' || coalesce($1.body, ''));
 $$;
```

Now I can:

```
 SELECT tsv(p) FROM pg_rocks_post p;
```

and it will just work.  I can also use the following form which would be more useful in some cases:

```
 SELECT p.tsv FROM pg_rocks_post.p;
```

or

```
 SELECT * from pg_rocks_post p WHERE plainto_tsquery('fat cat') @@ p.tsv;
```

Note you cannot omit the table alias since p.tsv is converted to tsv(p) as a function call.  This is nice object-like syntactic sugar that can make your life easier with PostgreSQL.

The next step is in indexing the output of the function:

```
  CREATE INDEX pg_rocks_post_tsv_idx ON pg_rocks_post(tsv(pg_rocks_post));
```

There we go.  no trigger needed and you get the index on the derived data.

Comment: Hi there @Chris Travers. And how would I use the created index during a search? Will it be use "automagically"?
Suppose I repeat the query `SELECT * from pg_rocks_post p WHERE plainto_tsquery('fat cat') @@ p.tsv;`. Will it use the created index?